# 422 error, devise/backbone

Tags: backbone.js, devise

I'm trying to set up a Rails app that uses Backbone with Devise for registration.

The response text in the error callback in the Chrome console says

```
responseText: "{"errors":{"email":["can't be blank"],"password":["can't be blank"]}}"
```

However, the log in the server says unprocessable entity

```
 Parameters: {"email"=>"pp@rr.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "registration"=>{"email"=>"pp@rr.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 4ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

I have a Backbone user model that sets the url for the save

```
UserRegistration = Backbone.Model.extend({
          url: '/users.json',
          paramRoot: 'user',

          defaults: {
            "email": "",
            "password": "",
            "password_confirmation": ""
          }
    });
```

In the associated view,  I get the attributes from the registration form, set them in the model, and then save the model

```
     var email = $('#email').val();
    var password_confirmation = $('#password_confirmation').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();

    this.model.set({email : email, password_confirmation: password_confirmation, password: password})



    this.model.save(this.model.attributes, {
      success: function(userSession, response) {
        console.log("success");
        console.log(userSession);
        console.log(response);
        console.log(this.model.url);

      },
      error: function(userSession, response) {
        console.log("error");
        console.log(userSession);
        console.log(response);

      }
    });
  }
```

After setting the model attributes (before saving) i did a console.log(this.model.attributes), and they are set

```
Object {email: "oo@gmail.com", password: "snowy", password_confirmation: "snowy"}
```

My User model looks like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

end
```

Can anyone make any suggestions?

There were some recent issues with a recent Devise release only responding to html, so I installed Devise 2.1.2 to make it respond with json to make it compatible with Backbone. That is not the issue here.

Comment: Are you using [backbone-rails](https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails)?

Comment: @muistooshort backbone-on-rails gem.

Comment: `paramRoot: 'user'` is supposed to put all the data inside the `'user'` namespace when talking to the server, no? But notice that everything in `params` is at the top level...

Comment: @muistooshort part of the devise related code I'm using (inluding paramRoot) was taken from someone who might have been using Backbone-Rails. I think paramRoot comes from that gem and is not part of Backbone core. That might be the problem. Do you know how I could add something similar to paramRoot without using that gem?

Answer (score 1):

paramRoot isn't part of Backbone core. In order to fix this problem, I had to include the sync library https://raw.github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/backbone_rails_sync.js from the Backbone-Rails gem to make user part of the param root

```
  url: '/users.json',
  paramRoot: 'user',
```